# XSD error when trying to upgrade Spring to 3.1 or above

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, xsd

Starting from Spring 3.0.4, when I try to upgrade it I get the following error. This happens in both the next minor version (3.1.0) and the absolutely newest version (5.3.13). It does not happen in the latest patch of my current minor version, 3.0.7.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from URL [file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd; lineNumber: 23; columnNumber: 20; cos-all-limited.1.2: An ''all'' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}'='{'max occurs'}'=1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.
```

After investigating, the problem seems to come from `spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd` (or in 5.3.13, `spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc.xsd`).

Comparing with 3.0's version of the same file (https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd), 3.1 (https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd) seems to have added a new tag, `<xsd:all minOccurs="0">`, around the line specified in the error. Manually editing the jar to change that `minOccurs="0"` to `minOccurs="1"` makes the problem go away. But obviously manually editing a maven dependency isn't an actual fix.

I'm thinking I'd need to make some change in my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml` files, but I have no idea what that change would be. The only mvc related tags in those files are `<mvc:resources .../>` and `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Please add the xml that leads to the error.

Comment: The error comes from `spring-mvc.xsd`. Like I said changing that file fixes the error, but it's part of a dependency, so changing it isn't actually a solution.

Comment: That wasn't my question, add your own XML not the spring ones. Thousands (so not millions) of people are of have used these XSD without errors, so I highly doubt that there is an error in those. The error is either in your own XML(s) or your XML parser (maybe too old).

Comment: Ok, looks like it was the parser. I didn't have one specifically defined which worked in 3.0,  but I guess became a problem for 3.1 and above. I added a couple dependencies (see my answer) and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by adding [`xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.12.1) and [`xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01) (not 2.0.2 which seems to just point to an old beta version for some reason) as dependencies. This let me upgrade to spring version 3.2.18. Trying to upgrade to 4.0 or above ran into other unrelated issues, as would be expected when changing major versions.

Comment: If you have a bit of a recent JDK I would just ditch those dependencies as the xml-api etc. is part of the JDK.

Comment: I'm using JDK 8 but adding those dependencies is what made it work, so idk.